# How to add separator to each item in for loop expect last one

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the loop below, how can I remove the comma from the latt key in the loop?

```
var result = 'These are the results: ';
jQuery.each(item['keyterms']['terms'],function(i,kw){
for (key in keywords){
sep = ',';
    if (keywords[key] > 5) result += '<span>' + key + sep + '</span>';
}}
```

Comment: If each key is wrapped in a `<span>` what good is the separator? Maybe you meant `'<span>' + key + '</span>' + sep`.

Comment: @Nimrod, the span is for css styling

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of inserting coma inside loop you can use standard javascript function [JOIN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
var results = Array();

for (key in keywords){
    if (keywords[key] > 5) results.push('<span>' + key + '</span>');
}

var message = 'These are the results: ' + results.join(',');
```

Comment: I'm sure this will work, but there's one problem. the result variable is previously declared and set to a string. Then its appended with the results of the for loop. How would you modify your answer accordingly? (I've modified my question to include that, sorry).

Comment: You can move your message few lines down, it would make your code more readable, otherwise rename results array to any other value to avoid collisions.

Answer (score 4):

Simple - instead of putting the separator **after** the key, put it **before**, and skip the first element (it's much easier to know when the element is first, than when it's last):

```
var first = true;
var result = '';
for (key in keys) {
  var sep = first ? '' : ', ';
  result += sep + key;
  first = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

note that for joining strings in JS the arrays join(separator) method is faster than the + operator. So I recommend Nazariy's solution. with a small change:

```
var result = Array();
for (key in keywords){
    if (keywords[key] > 5) result.push(['<span>', key, sep, '</span>'].join(''));
}}
result = result.join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just concerned about how to remove the last separator then this should work:

```
jQuery.each(item['keyterms']['terms'],function(i,kw){
for (key in keywords){
sep = ',';
    if (keywords[key] > 5) result += '<span>' + key + sep + '</span>';
}}
result = result.substring(0, result.length - (sep+"</span>").length) + "</span>");
```

Otherwise, Nazariy's join solution is a better way to create the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even add it?

```
var result = 'These are the results: ';
jQuery.each(item['keyterms']['terms'],function(i,kw){
var sep = '';
for (key in keywords){
  if (keywords[key] > 5) result += '<span>' + sep + key + '</span>';
  sep = ',';
}}
```