# How can I remove comma on last arrays loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, node.js, express

```
<% for(var i=0; i < 10; i++) { %>
<a href="#"><%= related[i] %></a>, 
<% } %>
```

Here is code. I need to remove comma on last result.

Comment: what templating engine is that? maybe a for loop isn't the right tool.

Comment: Please read our [ask] page - at least include a [mcve] for faster troubleshooting.   Question: what about adding an `if` statement (around the comma) that checks if the index (`i`) is not at the last item, does not add the comma?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add separator to each item in for loop expect last one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012806/how-to-add-separator-to-each-item-in-for-loop-expect-last-one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and easy answer is to put a conditional statement around the comma.

```
<% if(i < 9) { , } %>
```